# Temperature monitoring over Bluetooth

Tags: sensor, temperature, bluetooth-low-energy, android

I bought this temperature + pressure + other things sensor that operates over bluetooth.
Here it is : https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1HebxRSzqK1RjSZFjq6zlCFXaH/Module-de-capteur-d-acc-l-ration-de-pression-atmosph-rique-Bluetooth-4-0-BLE-SOC.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp

I'd like to use it for monitoring temperatures from a smartphone but I didn't find any documentation about how it works, only the BMP180 sensor doc.

I'm a real beginner in this field so I have several questions about how to implement this.

First I tried to get sensor data using linux tools (bluetoothctl, ...).

Does the module send automatically data over Bluetooth or do I need to send a command to get temperature ?

Edit : I succeded to get raw data using nRF Connect application : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JaumVJg3HM
By the way I found the datasheet for BMP180 but it does not seem to send the same data.
With nRF Connect I see an 8-byte chain for temperature and pressure. How to convert this to readable temperature ?

Comment: Read the datasheet that came with it, or you can download from the seller's website. If they won't supply one, even on request, you now have one valuable piece of information : no datasheet, no sale, from now on.

Comment: You do indeed need some form of documentation, be it a full detailed datasheet or even a simple protocol description. Many such BLE sensors actually just broadcast the info on their advertising data, it’s then just a matter of finding how it’s encoded. Download the nRF Connect app or other BLE scanner, it’ll tell you what the device advertises. You can also use Wireshark on your computer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JaumVJg3HM Here it is. I see the 4 first bytes of BMP180 value changing as I put the probe in the freezer so I guess it is the temperature while the 4 last bytes must be the pressure.

Yet I found no documentation for this board and it does not correspond to BMP180 documentation so the µcontroller must do the conversion at some point

Comment: @ Biologeek          already answered 7 days before       Some infos ...             https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350756290_A_Low-cost_Mobile_Real-time_Monitoring_System_for_Analyzing_Head_Position_and_Breathing_Patterns_in_Front_Crawl_Swimming/link/608a842d458515d315e35ca6/download

https://botland.store/withdrawn-products/8915-mbed-ble-sensors-tag.html

https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/8770518-nrf51822-beacon-kit-eval.html

https://www.linksprite.com/wiki/index.php?title=Mbed_BLE_Sensors_Tag

Comment: Thanks @Antonio51, I'll check deeper in your links but from it does not seem to match my needs as the sensor already sends temperature and pressure information but I don't know how to interpret them

Comment: @Biologeek   I have found that this module nRF51 (802) contains a BMP280 (p, T°), an AP3216 (module light ALS,PS, and IR Led) an MPU6050 (gyroscope and accel). I can't say more for now (not tested). AP3216 have an application on arduino https://www.roboremo.com/projects/arduino/reading-ap3216-with-arduino

Comment: I tested several known temperatures few days ago but couldn't find a linear relation between 3rd and 4th byte and actual temperature. Sometimes last byte changed, when I moved the sensor from the fridge to the oven for instance, while 3rd and 4th byte didn't move.

I guess there are some bytes for calibration but I still couldn't find documentation